# Laravel Disable JWT Auth when using oauth/authorize for passport

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, jwt, laravel-passport

I need to disable jwt auth when i try to do oauth/authorize that passport to do a authorization code grant. It needs to use the original oath of laravel ( I believe).

I figure I could use the client_id in the request do something like this:

```
if(request->client_id != null ){
  // jwt Auth
}
```

But not sure where I should put this code in laravel.

Comment: I finally got laravel Passport to work. You don't have to do anything with JWT-Auth. They will work together just fine.